# Plotly change function color after certain threshold

Tags: python, graph, plotly, plotly-dash

I have some data X, y, which I want to plot. I also want to make the function change color after a certain threshold t and the description to change after that threshold (I mean, when I hover on it, it should just display something else like "Background" instead of plotly data). I have uploaded a picture to clarify what I want to achieve. Does someone know how to do it?

[image: After threshold]

[image: Before threshold]

Comment: I have an idea. Maybe plot two functions on the same graph, the second one being the values that are after the threshold and just have a different color. Is that good?